# VBA insert a formula to add value of cell to another

Tags: excel, vba, formula

Im trying and failing to create a VBA formula for a command button which will take the value of cell S2 and add it with the value of the last cell of column G (this column is constantly being added to therefor making the row different each time). I want to place the result in the last cell of column I (again it is always being added to).

Help would be gratefully received, many thanks

Comment: I can see from your public profile that you have not taken the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/) yet. I suggest you do so and also take the time to read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Then come back and [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52632413/edit) your question to let us know what you've tried so far and where the problem is, exactly.

Answer (score 1):

This code would do that, you just need to have your command button run this sub:

```
Sub pasteLast()

Dim lrowG, lrowi As Integer

lrowG = Cells(Rows.Count, 7).End(xlUp).Row
lrowi = Cells(Rows.Count, 9).End(xlUp).Row

Cells(lrowi, 9).offset(1,0) = Range("s2") + Cells(lrowG, 7)

End Sub
```

just be careful because every time you click the button, it will add a value to column I whether it's unique or not. This would be better handled with a

```
Sub Worksheet_Change
```

event, where anytime S2 was changed it would add its value to column I.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to find the last cell reference in column G, then go to 1 row past the last cell reference in column I, and as the cell reference in column G to S2.

This should work:

Sub addToI()

```
Dim gTarget As String

Range("G1").Select
Selection.End(xlDown).Select
gTarget = Selection.Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1)

Range("I1").Select
Selection.End(xlDown).Select
Selection.Offset(1, 0).Select

ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=" & gTarget & "+R2C19"
```

End Sub